# Composer won't install package, requires ext-zip

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

Server runs PHP 8.  This is the error message returned when attempting to deploy.

**Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
Problem 1
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.22.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.22.0 requires ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.**

Here is the script section of my `gitlab-ci.yml` file, which is used to build the application.

```
   script:
    - apt-get update -yqq
    - apt-get install git nodejs libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq zip unzip
    - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql curl intl gd xml bz2 opcache bcmath
    - pecl install xdebug
    - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    - php composer.phar install
    - npm install
    - php artisan config:cache
```

How do i install PHP zip extension for PHP 8?
i've tried:

`apt get install zip`,
`pecl install php-pecl-zip`,
`apt get install libzip-dev`,
`docker-php-ext-install zip`,
`apt get install php-zip`

None of these have worked.  On local the above script section works with PHP 8 but doesn't work on AWS Ubuntu with PHP 8?  How do i solve?

Comment: `docker-php-ext-install zip`, should work whats the error from docker?

Comment: i get this error `Install of psr/http-factory failed`?

Answer (score 1):

You can install zip with following commands.

```
apt-get install -y libzip-dev zip  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-zip
```

also you should probably restart your nginx/apache server as well as php-fpm

Comment: tried that earlier and didn't work:  This was error message `E: Unable to locate package php8.0-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-zip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.0-zip'`